# How to send multiple web request and process them as fast as possible

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, task, webclient

I'm working on a C# winforms app and I have around 84 urls that I want to parse them using html agility pack

for 84 records it takes 150 seconds to complete the job with below code.

I was wondering what options do I have to make it run faster? any help is much appreciated!

Following is my code structure to do the job

```
public class URL_DATA
{
    public string URL { get; set; }
    public HtmlDocument doc  { get; set; }
}

then I call the below function to do the job

 public async Task ProcessUrls(string cookie)
 {
                var tsk = new List<Task>();
                //UrlsToProcess is List<URL_DATA>
                UrlsToProcess.ForEach(async data =>
                {
                    tsk.Add(Task.Run(async () => 
                    {
                      var htmToParse =  await ScrapUtils.GetAgilityDocby(cookie, data.URL);

                        var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
                        htmlDoc.LoadHtml(htmToParse);
                        data.doc = htmlDoc;

                    }));

                });
                await Task.WhenAll(tsk).ConfigureAwait(false);    
   }
```

and finally below is the method I use to get request string.

```
 public static async Task<string> GetAgilityDocby(string cookie, string url)
        {
            using (var wc = new WebClient())
            {
                wc.Proxy = null;// WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy;// GlobalProxySelection.GetEmptyWebProxy();
                wc.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, cookie);

                wc.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent,
                    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.86 Safari/537.36");
                wc.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
                test++;
                return await  wc.DownloadStringTaskAsync(url).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using a `ForEach` with asynchronous lambda. I have a suspicion that it makes your code run sequentially instead of parallel since each next iteration will do await.

So what you can do to figure that out for sure:

1. Check the maximum time of the operation for one URL, that time should be around how fast the whole thing should go (if you have enough bandwidth, memory and CPU).
2. Verify that you operations are indeed running in parallel. E.g. by outputting a counter to console. It should not be sequential and look random enough

You can change your task creation code to this e.g. to try:

```
var allTasks = myUrls.Select(url => Task.Run(() => {yourCode})
Task.WhenAll(allTasks);
```

Comment: There is no wait in the lambda, he just starts new threads there and awaits at the end.. It's definitely not the most elegant way to do this but should work

Comment: I would verify that with some logging to be sure. You might be right and this is not the problem at all, but won't hurt checking :) Do you know that there is no operation that takes very long time to complete?

Comment: Ilya the method ScrapUtils.GetAgilityDocby is async so I have to use await,
so I have tried it this way too but it seems like it takes 1.5-7 seconds to return string from the function and the loop waits for one request to end to start the other

Comment: You can do `.Result` instead. Not sure it's correct to do, but at least you will know whether it's parallel

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the minimum running Thread number by

```
ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(84,84);
```

This should speed things up alot.

As for the Task-Creation pointed out by Ilya, i would recomment you omit the Task.Run / AwaitAll part completely and use the Parallel mechanism, which was developed for exactly this kind of problem:

```
Parallel.ForEach(UrlsToProcess, data =>
{
    var htmToParse =  ScrapUtils.GetAgilityDocby(cookie, data.URL);

    var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
    htmlDoc.LoadHtml(htmToParse);
    data.doc = htmlDoc;
});
```

Comment: Where should I do this exactly?

Comment: Anytime before calling your function. Or in startup-code of your application. This needs to be called only ONCE, so no need to put it in the ProcessUrls function

Comment: with the Parallel.Foreach loop what happens is it immediately finishes the function that the loop is in, continues with other code while doing the loop background it starts all the request however each requests end 1 by 1, 
it's basicly works like a normal for loop except that it runs background

Comment: That's weird...because the parallels mechanism blocks definitely, see here (.net console program): https://pastebin.com/1PWStQ8C  can you perhaps upload your current sourcecode so we can examine?

Comment: Found the issue: you cannot async / await in parallel. But if you just omit that (have edited answer) then it works like a charm.

Comment: So my webclient method should be syncronous? Instead of await wc.downloadstringtaskasync I should use wc. Downloadstring()?

Comment: As this is done in a separate thread, you could do it this way, or you stick with the initial idea to spawn threads or use Ilyas approach. It's up to you. Anyway I think your core question has been answered?

Comment: Well both answers are great solutions however they do not work for me, whatever I do requests end one by one thus there is no change in performance :( I guess it because of the remote server and Im guessing there is nothing I can do

Comment: Hmm well i can't belive that a modern web server would handle incoming requests serially, so the issue has to be somewhere else. Have you tried your above source code with just setting the Threadpool limit?